# iOS Swift Detect Squares

Tags: swift

I am using Swift to detect squares on an image and I can't seem to get it to detect them. It seems to detect rectangles sometimes not sure if this is the correct approach. I am new to swift and image detection so if there is something else I can be doing to detect squares I would greatly appreciate getting pointed in the right direction.

From what I have found on searches is issues around detecting squares / rectangles and perspective. Not sure if this is the issue or just my lack of knowledge of Swift and image detection.

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcSWf.png)

```
lazy var rectangleDetectionRequest: VNDetectRectanglesRequest = {
        let rectDetectRequest = VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleDetectedRectangles)
        // Customize & configure the request to detect only certain rectangles.
        rectDetectRequest.maximumObservations = 8 // Vision currently supports up to 16.
        rectDetectRequest.minimumConfidence = 0.6 // Be confident.
        rectDetectRequest.minimumAspectRatio = 0.3 // height / width
        return rectDetectRequest
    }()

fileprivate func handleDetectedRectangles(request: VNRequest?, error: Error?) {
        if let nsError = error as NSError? {
            self.presentAlert("Rectangle Detection Error", error: nsError)
            return
        }
        // Since handlers are executing on a background thread, explicitly send draw calls to the main thread.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let drawLayer = self.pathLayer,
                let results = request?.results as? [VNRectangleObservation] else {
                    return
            }
            self.draw(rectangles: results, onImageWithBounds: drawLayer.bounds)
            drawLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

I have also changed minimumAspectRatio to 1.0 which from what information I have found would be a square and it still did not give the expected results.